# How to run sh file from another sh file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script file for monitoring my application, this script will be executed every 10 min by  setting cron job.

I would like to some more script files which are related to monitoring should be executed  along with master file. So I would like to include my scripts to master file. How to run those sh file from master sh file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190151/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-the-backgroung-and-get-no-output). If you want to run a script you can use:

```
./yourscript.sh
```

If your script has a loop, use:

```
./yourscript.sh&
```

If you want to get the console after starting scripts and you don't want to see it's output use:

```
./yourscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So, in the master file you'll have:

```
./yourscript1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
./yourscript2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
./yourscript3.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

They will start together.

Comment: You should avoid the redirections, at least until you know what you are doing. Debugging a failure when you have deliberately thrown away all the diagnostics is a nightmare in the making.

Answer (score 5):

Create file1.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
```

Create file2.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
details = `./file1.sh`
echo $details
```

give execute permission

```
chmod +x file1.sh
chmod +x file2.sh
```

Now run your file

```
./file2.sh
```

Output

```
Hello World
```