# Execute my Shell and Bash scripts without starting my terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm a user of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and in a future a user of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have a problem, when I run Ubuntu my **.bashrc** script doesn't work unless I open the terminal.

This is a problem because, for example, the paths I write doesn't work unless I execute the programs from the terminal.

**Are there an user config startup file for Ubuntu and not for the terminal?**

P.D.:Maybe I don't explain very well, in other words, I'd like to execute mi scripts on Ubuntu startup without using the terminal.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. `.bashrc` is a shell startup file which means it affects `the shell` whenever you start it up

Comment: try this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190151/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-the-backgroung-and-get-no-output

Comment: Question has been answered before. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Do you want code to run every time you login, or every time the system boots?  The words `Ubuntu startup` refer to the latter.

Comment: BroSlow: Thank you very much! I've forgotten this!

Answer (score 3):

Shell initialisation files (`.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.) are intended for preparing the user's (interactive) environment.

For standalone scripts, it's better to make them independent from the environment, including
$HOME, $PATH, etc.

If you need to share code (functions, configuration) with other scripts, store that in a separate 
shell library that you source from a known location, either through a fixed path or from a
path relative to the script's own location.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the line below at the start of your script file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '/etc/bashrc' ~/.bashrc
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bashrc   # --> Read /etc/bashrc, if present.
```

by default /etc/bashrc gets loaded when opening a console.

What are you trying to do - if you want to do something without it being executed as part of a console and more to do with system startup ? then you need to look into modifying existing service or adding a new service.

If this is related to when users ssh or connect it via console then its be bashrc file