# I run a production mode of play framework ，how to keep it running background

Tags: java, deployment, playframework, production

"./scorpio -Dhttp.port=10000 & "

[image]

doesn't work too 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diW6U.png)

I use "activator dist" to deploy my play project，and i start my application as the fisrt pic, ./scorpio  -Dhttp.port=10000 -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true -Dplay.crypto.secret=QCY?Anfk?aZ?iwrNwnxIR6
 how to start it so the application will run on background

Comment: i have tried "ctrl+D", it doesn't work.

Comment: how about appending an ampersand? ie. 'activator dist &'

Comment: thx~     i add a "&"   0.0     that worked

Answer (score 0):

It is not play related. It is about how to start any other java / shell application in the background.

It is already answered for example here:
[How to run a shell script in the background and get no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190151/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-the-background-and-get-no-output)

Answer (score 0):

As @Micahl mentioned it's not play related but any script running on linux. `nohup` is your friend. read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out)

`nohup ./scorpio -Dhttp.port=10000 >/dev/null 2>&1`

make sure the application logging is configured properly to a file as the above command will redirect all stdout to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running play app in production I am recommending to build a system package with `sbt-native-packager`. Builded packages use system level services to run app in background, have proper configuration and have convenient versioning tools.